# How to retrieve data-attribute from jsp to java

Tags: java, jsp

Based on the selection made from `Select` in my JSP, I want to either run code A or code B in my java code after pressing `Submit`.

I also want to be able to add new options to my `Select` now and then, so having 
all the logic in my java code would not be suitable for me.

To solve this, I have added the data-attribute in my `Select` like so:

```
<select name="fruit">
    <option data-t="1" value="apple">apple</option>
    <option data-t="1" value="orange">orange</option>
    <option data-t="2" value="banana">banana</option>
    <option data-t="2" value="lemon">lemon</option>
    </select>
```

I can easily retrieve the selected value via `request.getParameter("fruit");`
But how do I retrieve the data-attribute?

If I could retrieve the data-attribute I could just make an if statement in my java code to execute code A if data-t = 1, else execute B.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't (not directly). As a workaround, maybe you could use values like "1|apple", "1|orange" etc and split on the "java side"

Comment: Have a hidden parameter that you update with java script.

Comment: Yes I could create a new variable based on choice, I thought this was bad practice, since its 1 more step, and also I will be dependent on javascript. But maybe this is the only way :)